# Public windows docker image for azure machine learning

Tags: docker, azure-machine-learning-service

Our machine learning workflow requires use of a custom windows .pyc file. Where can I find a windows docker image file.

I am puzzled by this statement from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-custom-docker-image#create-a-custom-base-image. Is it really true that azure cannot use windows images?

```
Image requirements: Azure Machine Learning only supports Docker images that provide the following software:

Ubuntu 16.04 or greater.
Conda 4.5.# or greater.
Python 3.5.# or 3.6.#.
```

Searching on docker hub also did not turn up anything promising

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. The Azure ML Service currently only supports Linux for dockerized execution.